# Install WhatsApp in Amazon Fire

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

Amazon Fire has no Google Play Store, but [an article on How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/232726/how-to-install-the-google-play-store-on-your-amazon-fire-tablet/) took care of it. Another problem is that I have some application that is not compatible with the tablet.

At first, I thought that's because Amazon tablet doesn't have location. It has location. I can just enable it. The reason is because Amazon tablet doesn't have SIM slots. Now that's tricky. However, APKPure solves that problem.

When I need to verify my SMS by inserting a one-time code, I just proceed as usual.

Usually, there is an error message saying

> {THIS_APP} is having problem with Google Play Service

However, for most apps, it doesn't matter. SMS got sent anyway. I just receive it from another phone and insert the OTP (One-Time Password). Voila. Everything is set.

For WhatsApp, I never get SMS. It's as if WhatsApp realizing there is an error doesn't do even bother sending SMS. I wonder why.

Other apps see an error and send SMS any way that I can verify. Not WhatsApp.

Anyone has a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. When it fails, just keep pressing the button that says they will send OTP and keep pressing next. It doesn't always work on the first try. But keep doing it works.

So basically install and get OTP like usual. However, if it doesn't work keep pressing it. Try again and again. Eventually, it works. So far so good.

The only reason why I need SIM is for the internet. I very rarely use my phone. So I can WhatsApp and use any apps I wish.

Comment: The button that makes you get SMS. I think it's NEXT or something after you put your phone number. Doesn't always work but keep trying

Comment: No longer work. I kept trying it never works again